# Taking ownership of NTFS folder locks out user

Tags: windows-server-2003, ntfs, network-share

Administrators were denied access to a NTFS folder.  After I made Administrators the folder owner a user complained that they could no longer access the folder.  The only way I think this would have happened was if they were the former owner and the ACL was empty.  What else might have caused this?

Comment: Are you going to tell us what the permissions are set to or do you want us to just take a guess?

Comment: If Administrators were denied access and you took ownership of the folder, the DACL will have been replaced. You will need to reconfigure the ACL entries to grant access to users requiring access.

Comment: @John - I don't understand the question

Comment: @Lewis - What do you mean the DACL will have been replaced?  The DACL on other folders I changed the owner seems intact or at least there are ACEs in them.

Comment: If you are denied access to a folder which you then choose to take ownership of, all permissions are replaced. You should have received a warning message saying: **[You do not have permission to read the contents of directory DIRECTORY folder. Do you want to replace the directory permissions with permissions granting you Full Control? All permissions will be replaced if you press Yes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7kXFj.jpg).**

Comment: @Lewis - thx - so I conducted a test.  Created a new folder, removed all ACEs, granted full control to another user, then made that user the owner.  Checked that I was denied access to folder, then took ownership again.  I didn't get the warning message and the ACE for the other user was still there.

Comment: @zen - That is very strange. I have performed the same test both locally and remotely but received the same warning both times?

Answer (score 1):

you're removing special ACL for "Owner", you need to duplicate it manually before taking ownership